# Retrieving specified columns from a list of csv files to create a data data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a situation where I need to get a column (or a variable) from each csv file (total files = 40) and my final result should have a dataframe containing 40 columns of the same variable.
I tried my level best by using this site and this is what i have done so far:

```
$#*******************************************
theFiles <- list.files(pattern=glob2rx('*.csv'))
datafile<- lapply(theFiles,read.csv, header= T, sep = ",")

rain<- vector()
head(theFiles)
All<- for (i in 1:length(datafile)) {
  #do stuff here
  data_from_csv <- as.data.frame(datafile[i])
  rain <- list(rain, data_from_csv[,8]) 
# extract column no 8 from each file 
# if i use vector then its producing only one 
} 
#*****************************$
```

The result is a list(list(list(...etc of values, structure and name which does not necessarily make sense, except the value. I can't check the dimension because it is a list and i couldn't change to dataframe because only 2 lists appear eventhough I had 40 files.
Therefore, I request all of you to sort out the mess.
The reason for getting into different columns is that they are from different locations.

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Try `read.csv.sql` function from `sqldf` package. It lets you directly pick specific columns from the csv files.

```
data <- read.csv.sql(theFile, sql="select col8 from file")
```

Comment: Its a useful package, especially if one is familiar with `sql`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
rain<- list()

All <- for (i in 1:length(datafile)) {
  #do stuff here
  rain[[i]] <- datafile[[i]][,8]
# extract column no 8 from each file 
# if i use vector then its producing only one 
}
```

Comment: Oh that was quick, u guys really owe a treat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sapply` over your `datafile` object like this:

```
as.data.frame( sapply( datafile , `[` , 8 ) )
```

Or you can even step back to your list of files and do it like this:

```
as.data.frame( sapply( theFiles , function(x) ( read.csv( x , h = T ) )[,8] ) )
```

### What if the imported columns have different lengths

It depends how you want to fill in the NAs. A naive way of doing it would be to find the length of the longest imported column and then make all the shorter columns match it's length by adding NAs on to the end. This is very likely to be not what you want, but in case it is you could acheive it like this:

```
cols <- sapply( theFiles , function(x) ( read.csv( x , h = T ) )[,8] )
mx <- max( sapply( cols , length ) )
as.data.frame( sapply( cols , function(x) { if( length( x ) == mx ) x else  c( x , rep( NA , mx - length(x) ) ) } ) )
```

Comment: Ok thank you. What will be the possible solution if the files contain different no of rows? At what stage do i fill in the NAs?

Comment: @user2339731 this is a bit more involved and probably a seperate question. For instance, how do you know where an NA should be? If one column has 100 values and another has 50 values, where do you put the 50 NAs to make it the same length as the first column? Do you have some rownames to match on? I would ask this as a seperate question.

Comment: @user2339731 I added a solution for that, but as I said it depends on how you want to *fill in the NAs*. I think it's unlikely you want to just add NAs to the end of each column to make them the same length.

Comment: hi Simon..... it did work. and thanks.... but i managed to cut down the time series later by using the window,,,,function

Comment: @Khandu you should consider adding that as an answer then to show what you did for future visitors, and then accepting your own answer by pressing the green tick, that way the question can be removed from the unanswered questions stack, and helps to keep the site clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `lapply` and then a loop seems a bit messy to me. It's easier (and just as fast) to read everything in in one loop:

```
theFiles <- list.files(pattern=glob2rx('*.csv'))

rain <- list()
for (file in theFiles) {
    d <- read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
    rain[[i]] <- d[,8]
}
```

As was mentioned you could also use tools to only read in column 8 (e.g. using `sqldf`, `LaF`, or `colbycol`) but I would only do that when there are memory/speed issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
theFiles <- list.files(pattern=glob2rx('*.csv'))

#read the files 
datafile<- lapply(theFiles,read.csv, header= T, sep = ",")
head(theFiles)
name<- data.frame(theFiles)
rowseq <- seq_len( max(vapply(datafile,nrow, integer(1))))
keylist <- lapply(datafile,function(x) { x[[8]][rowseq]  }) #row number 8
names(keylist) <- paste(name,theFiles,sep="_") # name the column by file names
Rainfall<- do.call(data.frame,keylist)
```

However, an assumption is that all files contain a equal no. of time series. For unequal no of series, we can modify simmons code.......

thanks everybody......
khandu