# How can I specify which columns to select using read.table in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have a dataset with 100 columns and it doesn't have a header.

I have an int vector that consists of some numbers ranges between 1 to 100. For example, a vector with "2 5 62 78".

Now when I read the dataset using read.table, all I want is to select column 2, 5, 62 and 78 from the dataset. How can I do that? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320667/retrieving-specified-columns-from-a-list-of-csv-files-to-create-a-data-data-fram

Comment: Take a look at `?read.table` option `colClasses`. If you set it to `"NULL"` (that's a character), it will skip the column.

Comment: @ilir you should post that as the answer.  Tho' I suspect for a 100-column file, it'll be much easier to do `foo<-read.table(datafile); foo<-foo[,c(2,5,62,78)]` than `foo<-read.table(datafile,colClasses=c(rep('numeric',1),NULL,rep('numeric',2),...)`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you can populate the vector of classes beforehand, and use some tricks. See my answer for something I've had to use a lot in the past.

Comment: @ilir  Yep,  I upvoted on account of your detailed approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the option `colClasses` of `read.table()` (and the derivative functions). It allows you to pass a `character` vector with the classes of each column in the data. If you set that to `"NULL"` the column will be skipped. You can set the whole thing to `"NULL"` and then only change the ones you want to import (based on their class).

Proof of concept below.

```
cc <- rep('NULL', 100)       ## skip all 100 columns
cc[c(2, 5)] <- 'integer'     ## 2 and 5 are integer
cc[c(62, 58)] <- 'character' ## 62 and 58 will be imported as character
df <- read.csv('really-wide-data.csv', colClasses=cc)
```

Comment: Thanks @ilir, for some reasons cc[c(2,5)] <- 'integer' gives me this error (Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : ), but if I assign it with 'numeric', everything works out correctly!

Comment: @alwc that may be because the data is not integer. I don't know what your columns have. The example was meant to show that you can specify the class of each variable.