# R : How to select and extract specific columns using colClasses?

Tags: r, csv

Using R, I want to read a large `'.csv'` file. To make it efficient ,I would like to read only the columns of interest by mentioning their index(indices) or column names and store the result in another variable.

I am using `read.csv()` function.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242812/how-can-i-specify-which-columns-to-select-using-read-table-in-r/23243567#23243567) may help

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using `read.csv.sql` from the `sqldf` package. You use an SQL SELECT to filter the columns, eg:

```
read.csv.sql("file.csv", sql="SELECT col1, col2 FROM file")
```

SQLite handles the filtering, so you can load portions of files that would be too large otherwise.